# Assign the frequency of each value to dataframe with new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, duplicates

I try to set up a Dataframe that countains a column called frequency.
This column should show how often the value is present in a specific column of the dataframe in every row. Something like this:

```
Index  Category  Frequency    
     0        1         1
     1        3         2
     2        3         2
     3        4         1
     4        7         3
     5        7         3
     6        7         3
     7        8         1
```

This is just an example

I already tried it with value_counts(), however I only receive a value in the last line of the appearing number. 
In the case of the example

```
Index  Category  Frequency    
     0        1         1
     1        3         N.A
     2        3         2
     3        4         1
     4        7         N.A
     5        7         N.A
     6        7         3
     7        8         1
```

It is very important that the column has the same number of rows as the dataframe, preferably appended to the same dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Frecuency']=df['Category'].map(df['Category'].value_counts())
```

or [pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Frecuency']=df['Category'].replace(df['Category'].value_counts())
```

**Output:**

```
   Index  Category  Frecuency
0      0         1          1
1      1         3          2
2      2         3          2
3      3         4          1
4      4         7          3
5      5         7          3
6      6         7          3
7      7         8          1
```

**Details**

```
df['Category'].value_counts()
7    3
3    2
4    1
1    1
8    1
Name: Category, dtype: int64
```

using `value_counts` you get a series whose `index` are the elements of the category and the `values` ​​is the count. So you can use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) or [pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to create a series with the `category` values ​​replaced by those in the count. And finally assign this series to the `frequency` column

Answer (score 2):

```py
df['Frequency'] = df.groupby('Category').transform('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using group by like below

```py
df.groupby("Category") \
.apply(lambda g: g.assign(frequency = len(g))) \
.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```